# How to capture an html form submit with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Currently I have several text inputs and then a type image submit button. On the submit button I have onmouseover, onmouseout, etc.. This sends those to a javascript function that handles change of images for a hover effect.  What I wanna do is submit the form and then do some checking like do passwords match and such.  Would I do something with the action attribute of the form tag to submit it to a javascript function?

Comment: Use the form's submit handler. e.g. `<form onsubmit="…" …>`.

Comment: can you please add some sample code?

Comment: From a useability standpoint, PLEASE have your client-side checks done as each control is modified, instead of only on submit.  I hate websites that have arbitrary password requirements that don't tell me until after I've hit "submit".  (And from a security standpoint, assume server-side that the form was cracked and not a single client-side check was ran.)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I recommend using something like jQuery. It makes the code a lot easier to manage. Here's how you'd do it in jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    var validated = true;
    // do form validation

    if (!validated) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    return validated;
});
```

Here's how you'd do it in pure javascript:

```
// function to make sure we add the event correctly no matter which browser
function addEvent(evnt, elem, func) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) {  // W3C DOM
        elem.addEventListener(evnt,func,false);
    } else if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
        elem.attachEvent("on"+evnt, func);
    } else { // No much to do
        elem[evnt] = func;
    }
}

// get first form on page
var form = document.forms[0];
addEvent('submit', form, function(e) {
    var validated = true;
    // do form validation

    if (!validated) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    return validated;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form onsubmit="return cancel()"><input type="submit" /></form>
<script>
function cancel()
{
    //code validation
    var validated = false;
    if(!validated)return false;
    else return true;
}
</script>
```